# Cycling ringtones?

Tags: ios, applications, ringtones

Is it currently possible through an app (regardless of whether the iPhone is jailbroken) to cycle through different ring tones for each new message and call that comes in?

For example, if a user has 50 ringtones on their phone, the ringtones would cycle with every incoming message or call.

Comment: How would you identify a ringing phone as yours if there are so many ring tones?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, unless the device is jailbroken, this wouldn't be possible. The APIs available to Apple iOS developers don't allow the change of system level events. Even creating ringtones on the device to use is somewhat convoluted. Particularly pre-iOS 5, and iOS 6 has improved that somewhat.

So, unless it is a jailbreak tweak, this won't be possible.